# Reference manual for Apache Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig, dataflow, manual

Pig is a dataflow programming environment for processing very large files. Pig's language is called Pig Latin.

Does anyone know of a good reference manual for [PigLatin](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/)? I'm looking for something that includes all the syntax and commands descriptions for the language. Unfortunately the wiki page in Pig wiki is broken.

Comment: do you actually mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin or do you mean http://wiki.apache.org/pig/?

Comment: I think the poster was talking about the Apache Pig Latin. Totally valid programming question. Please reopen it.

Comment: I edited the question to add a link to Apache Pig so that people aren't confused.

Comment: @akaDruid, thanks for doing some research to help this question.

Comment: Wiki works fine for me. http://wiki.apache.org/pig/FrontPage

Comment: @Out Into Space, I was curious to see if the syntax used real pig latin; something like "oreachfay Away enerategay tay + uway;" would have brightened my day :)

Answer (score 5):

The reference manual I work with is in the Wiki: [Pig Latin Manual](http://hadoop.apache.org/pig/docs/r0.2.0/piglatin.html).

It contains all Pig Latin commands with their syntax and examples.

Answer (score 3):

As Craig Stuntz mentioned, try the wiki:
http://wiki.apache.org/pig/FrontPage

Posting since this is an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I use these quite often:

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.6.0/piglatin_ref1.html

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.6.0/piglatin_ref2.html

I hope its handy for you too.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/Index

Answer (score 0):

one can find the documents in the dist. download the latest tar and lookup docs.

Answer (score 0):

updating to the latest pig version - http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/